# Back propogation on multi layered neural networks

Tags: c#, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

I am making a neural network system with c# without using any libraries or Accord.Net. But i am stuck on how to back propogate my error. Do i have to include all layers that i have already propagated to the next layer, or only the previous layer gets in the equation?

**Edit for more information:**

My network structure is mostly dynamic. It creates a neural network with user input with how many layers and node count per layer. It has input and output layer created based on the dataset used. It can use linear, sigmoid, tanh or relu activation functions on layers, and you can mix match them per layer.

I do understand how backpropogation works and its use. But every example i see use it on only 3 layered structures with 1 input, 1 hidden and 1 output layer. They calculate output layer error and update its weights. Then they calculate hidden layer's error with output layer included.

My problem starts here. They dont show as if only the layer before the hidden layer (thinking as you go right to left for back propogation) is included, or all the layer till output layers are included in the error equation.

For visualization

***input layer ---> hidden layer 1 ---> hidden layer 2 ---> output layer***

In this example, when i calculate the hidden layer1's error and weight update, do i only include hidden layer 2, or hidden layer 2 + output layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder what you mean by "include". Backpropagation is supposed to compute the gradient. The gradient is the derivative of each variable against the loss function (you call this the error, but that term is not quite precise. It's not an error, it's a slope). After the gradient is computed all parameters (the "weights") are updated at once.

Computing the gradient essentially is numeric differentiation. If you have `a * b = c`, you have all `a`, `b` and `c` and `gradient(c)`, then it is easy to compute the gradient for `a` and `b` as well (`gradient(a) = b * gradient(c)`).

So you push the gradient layer by layer backwards. For each layer you only need the gradient of the next layer. Frameworks such as TensorFlow do this automatically for you. The technique works for any computational graph, not just for neural networks of the structure you described. Understanding the general concept of numeric differentiation along a computational graph first makes it easy to understand the special case of a neural network.

Comment: My supervisor forbid me to use any frameworks nor libraries for this project. So i have to write all algorithms and logic by myself. Thats why i struggled in this topic. Can you expand this a bit more? When i calculate the error and gradient at the output, how i should use them to propogate in the deeper layers?

Comment: Push down the gradient layer by layer. You only need the gradient of the following layer to compute the previous layer. If you want a full description find a tutorial. Here, you need to ask pointed questions about a concrete issue.

Comment: I recently wrote a neural network by hand. The way I was able to understand the computation was to think about what TensorFlow would do. Reverse compute the gradient for each operation. An NN layer is output = activationFunction(inputs * weights + biases). So the gradient at the `+` (`gradient(inputs * weights + biases)`) is, for example, `activationFunction'(inputs * weights + biases) * gradient(output)` if I'm not mistaken. Then, you again push that gradient further through the `+` and the `*`.

Comment: I had trouble following the math formulas in NN tutorials but this operation by operation view helped me a lot. I think math formulas are a horrible way to explain neural networks. The intuition is so easy and the math just obscures it to the layman.

Comment: You are a life saver sir. This is the exact problem i had. I couldnt understand anything about the formulas but this analogy makes everything clear for me. Thanks a lot ^_^.

Comment: Hello, sorry for bothering again, but i am still having struggle on implementing back propogation on a  neural network. All of the other modules are ready to use. Can you help me again please?

Comment: Sure___________